# finding if the selected item is in a set

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a bit of jquery and javascript mashed up in this weird hodgepodge of code.

```
var SELECTED_ELEMENT;  //this ends up being a JS array of ELEMENTS like the following line.
SELECTED_ELEMENT.push($(this).closest(".draggable"));
//Now i wanted to select stuff
$(".draggable").click(function(){
   var found = 0;
   for (var i = 0; i < SELECTED_ELEMENT.length; i++){
      if(SELECTED_ELEMENT[i] == this){
         found = 1;
      }
   }
   if(found == 1){
      alert("yep");
   }else{
      alert("nope");
   }
});
//this doesnt seem to do what i want.
```

The question at hand is that this is never returning true, even when it is.  I was just trying to find a way to in javascript search the array for it.  You would think that a simple search through the array would figure it out, but possibly an improper reference to 'this'

Comment: Its not in my actual code, I just had a conference to present to so i couldnt adjust it right when it was posted.  I figured people would understand what i was doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some issues, like `int found = 0` which isn't even javascript. Then you are pushing jQuery objects to an array, and comparing them to dom elements.

Push the elements instead:

```
var selectedElements = [],

    closest = $(this).closest(".draggable")[0];

if( closest ) {
    selectedElements.push( closest );
}

$(".draggable").click( function() {
    var index = selectedElements.indexOf(this);

    alert( index > -1 ? "yep" : "nope" );
});
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/sqj42/

Comment: I am sorry @Esailija, check it now.

Comment: yea, thats not an error.  Its var in my actual code, and was in a conference so i couldnt adjust it

Answer (score 1):

In your second line you have `SELECT_ELEMENT` instead of `SELECTED_ELEMENT`.

And this is shorter:

```
if(SELECTED_ELEMENT.indexOf(this) != -1)
    alert('yep');
else
    alert('nope');
```

Comment: yea, fixed it, that was just a syntactic error and not related to the question at hand, which is searching through ah array through on click looking for a match.

Answer (score 0):

The real answer i was looking for that i found:

My search is wrong.  it should be:

```
var found = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < SELECTED_ELEMENT.length; i++){
   if ( this == SELECTED_ELEMENT[i][0] ){  //the key is the extra [0] as the stored element is a jquery object, so it needs to be de-referenced by selecting the object itself and not the jquery wrapper-thingy for it..
      found = 1;
   }
}
if(found == 1){
    alert("yep");
}else{
    alert("nope");
}
```